# How to interpret and view the complete permutation feature plot in jupyter?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am trying to generate the feature importance plot through `Permutation Feature Importance` plot. I am trying to kind of make sure whether the features returned through different approaches is stable. To select optimal features. Can we get a `p-value` or something of that sort which can indicate the feature is significant? If I could do it with `PFI`, i could be more confident but looks like the results are entirely opposite

Here is my code to generate the plot

```
logreg=LogisticRegression(random_state=1) # i also tried with Random Forest
logreg.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
perm = PermutationImportance(logreg,random_state=1).fit(X_train_std,y_train)
eli5.show_weights(perm)   #find the issue with plot below
```

**Questions**

1) The feature that I see at the top was non-significant in other approaches (Chi-square,Xgboost Feature importance, Logistic Regression stats model summary etc) but here i see it at the top which I am a bit shocked. Is it ordered in a decreasing order or ascending order?

2) I understand `PFI` randomizes value to see the reduction in model error. If first row (`X18`) is an important feature, then it's totally opposite of my other approaches. Am I making any mistake here? What should I be looking/checking in a situation like this? Or should I apply `PFI` only on already selected important features?

3) How do I make the jupyter cell to display to all rows. Currently it doesn't show remaining 35 rows as shown below . I have already set pandas_set column width, rows etc

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: be careful about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60489934/5025009

Answer (score 1):

Use the  attribute **`top=`** to solve Questions 3, as in **`eli5.show_weights(perm,top=100)`**. More in the [docs](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html?highlight=top).

For question 1 and 2, I've been in a similar situation. As far as I know, different approaches do have different outputs. Each approach has its own criteria. For TREE approaches, such as `DecisionTree`, `xgboost`, `catboost`, `GBRT`, etc., in the process of building a tree. The more a feature is used, the more important it becomes. But other approaches don't.